# XOR javascript. funcion xor que coge 2 valores booleanos. Si los dos son diferentes, resultado true. Si los dos son el mismo, el resultado es false

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando realizar una función XOR que coge 2 valores booleanos. Si los dos son diferentes, el resultado es true. Si los dos son el mismo, el resultado es false.

I.e.: The calls xor(true, false) and xor(false, true) should return true. The calls xor(true, true) and xor(false, false) should return false.

El error: `xor(true, false) does not return true, but false.`

```
function xor(a,b){
  if (a || a ) 
    return  !(a || a);
  else( b || b)
    return ( b || b);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Podrías usar el operador [Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR) (`^`). Como el operador devuelve un 1 o un 0, si necesitas que devuelve un valor booleano tendrías que convertirlo con `Boolean()`.

```js
console.log(Boolean(true ^ true));
console.log(Boolean(true ^ false));
console.log(Boolean(false ^ true));
console.log(Boolean(false ^ false));
```

Si lo que quieres es construirlo tú mismo, la condición es muy sencilla. `((a && !b) || (!a && b))`

```js
function xor(a, b) {
  return (a && !b) || (!a && b);
}

console.log(xor(true, true));
console.log(xor(true, false));
console.log(xor(false, true));
console.log(xor(false, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero quisiera comentar unos detalles de tu código:

- No es obligatorio, pero en general se considera una buena práctica usar siempre llaves (`{...}`) en las expresiones de control de flujo: if, for, while, etc.
- No tiene sentido intentar poner una condición en la sentencia `else`.

Estos dos detalles hacen que el código que tienes se comporte de un modo que seguramente no esperas, y para explicarlo voy a poner las llaves que faltan sin modificar el comportamiento:

```javascript
function xor(a,b){
  if (a || a ) {
    return  !(a || a);
  } else {
    ( b || b)
  }
  return ( b || b);
}
```

Realmente no afecta mucho en este caso porque el código del else es inocuo, pero en muchos escenarios causaría un error, es algo a tener en cuenta.
Por otro lado, tu código ahora mismo lo que hace es:

```
function xor(a,b) {
  if (a) {
    return !Boolean(a);
  }
  return Boolean(b)
}
```

Cuando lo que quieres hacer es realmente es comprobar que a y b son distintos, que puedes hacer de dos maneras:

```js
function xor(a,b) {
  return a!==b; //(!!a) !== (!!b) si quieres convertir a booleanos a y b
}

function xor2(a,b) { // asume que las entradas son booleanas
  return !!(a^b);
}

[
  [false, false],
  [false, true],
  [true,false],
  [true,true],
  ['','a']
].forEach(([a,b]) => {
  console.log(`Para las entradas ${a} y ${b}, obtenemos:`, xor(a,b), xor2(a,b));
});
```